# How can I cancel a delayed shutdown?

Tags: windows-server-2008

After loading some updates, I got that box that allows a delay in the shutdown but only up to 4 hours. I took the 4 hour delay, but would like to abort being reminded to shutdown and, if possible, abort the shutdown altogether. Our system reboots once a week on the weekends.

I have noticed if that reminder dialog box returns after a delay and is not answered, shutdown happens after a few minutesanyway, at least on a Win7 workstation.

I've looked on technet to see what commands were available, so shutdown /a only aborts an active shutdown.

My questions are:

Is it possible to postpone the shutdown outright?

It is possible at least to postpone the little dialog box that will come around four hours from now?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please vote to close. I already have flagged asking it to be closed.

Comment: We have a number of questions which cover this, though this was the first one I found. A quick search will reveal others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, enter `shutdown /a` to cancel the shutdown.

To schedule a shutdown, use the `shutdown` command with the `/t xxx` flag, where "`xxx'" is the number of seconds that you would like to delay.

Run `shutdown /?` to see all options available.  For a reboot, you proabably want `/r`

Personally, I usually add `/t xxx` to most commands, entering a small amount (1-5 seconds) of a delay when I want it to run immediately.

Comment: Didn't work. The message said there was no active shutdown in place. This is what's so unnerving about it. You can't just download and reboot when you want to like to good old days. That dialog will come back up in 4 hours, and I have to be there to dismiss it again.

Comment: Ok, then it's not the shutdown that's scheduled; it's the auto-updates.  You'll have to disable the Automatic Updates service.

Comment: What's the name of the service? I'm looking in services and don't see it.

Comment: "Windows Update" (a.k.a. "wuauserv")

Comment: Just for the record, I recommend re-enabling it, running the updates, and rebooting at the nearest opportunity.